# Not able to run ALTER query through logstash JDBC plugin

Tags: oracle, logstash

I am not able to run `ALTER` queries on my Oracle database through Logstash.
Below is the snippet from the config file:

```html
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<SID>"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        schedule => "48 11 * * thu"
        statement => "ALTER INDEX <tablename> REBUILD ONLINE"
    }
}
```

Getting error: `Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>Java::JavaSql::SQLRecoverableException, :message=>"Closed Connection"}`

The same config is working fine if I run a `select` query and I am able to see the logs in Kibana.
Also, I am able to execute the `ALTER` query through SQL Developer tool with same user that I am passing here. So this means there's no access related issues.

Is this even possible to run `ALTER` queries through Logstash? Not sure what I am missing here. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't use Logstash. But, what does "I am not able to run ALTER" mean? Did you get any error? If so, which one? If not, what happened?

Comment: Sorry, i had forgotten to add the error details. It's updated now.